# need help to identify this html code using tables

Tags: html

I need help at what codes they use on the image, thats all

[image]

Comment: please share the markup that you have tried

Comment: is it your code?

Comment: if it's your code then share html

Comment: Just view source of the web page (HTML code)

Comment: @MatejJ yes thats best idea ,But i think @ JuiShan has this image only. And s/he is not clear with rowspan and colspan

Comment: This looks like some kind of assignment. Take note that SO is not he place where people will solve your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
May you have to add a border, but the skeletal structure ist given.

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Purchased Equipments (June, 2006) </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Item Num#</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Item Pic</td>
    <td>Item Description</td>
    <td>Price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</td>
    <td>Expense</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Img 1</td>
    <td>IBM Clone Computer</td>
    <td>$ 400</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</td>
    <td>$ 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Img 2</td>
    <td>1GB RAM Module for Computer</td>
    <td>$ 50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</td>
     <td>$ 14</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Purchased Equipments (June, 2006) </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact representation , consider some fine tuning @laura

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>HTML Table</title>
</head>

<body>


   <table border="3" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="grey" cellpadding="3">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
            <center><b>Purchased Equipments (June, 2006)</b></center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2"><b>Item Num#</b></td>
         <td rowspan="2"><b>Item Picture</b></td>
         <td>
            <center><b>Item Description</b></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><b>Price</b></center>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><b>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</b></td>
         <td><b>Expense</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">1.</td>
         <td rowspan="2"><img height="80" width="100" src="lap.jpg"></img></td>
         <td>IBM Clone Computer</td>
         <td>$ 400.00</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</td>
         <td>$ 20.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">2.</td>
         <td rowspan="2"><img height="80" width="100" src="board-chip.jpg"></img></td>
         <td>1GB RAM Module for Computer</td>
         <td>$ 50.00</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>Shipping Handling, Installation, etc</td>
         <td>$ 20.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
            <center><b>Purchased Equipments (June, 2006)</b></center>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>


</body>

</html>
```